# Multiple individual data cannot be sent on mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia

Tags: javascript, audio, qmediarecorder

```
console.log("Starting recording ...")
    audioChunks = []
    recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', evt => {
        
        if(evt.data.size > 0  && close_record === 1) {
            

            audioChunks.push(evt.data);

            // Giữ lại chỉ 10 audio chunk mới nhất
            // if (audioChunks.length > 10) {
            //     audioChunks = audioChunks.slice(-10);
            // }
            blob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'video/webm'  });
 
            async function makepredict(){
                let response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/audio/`, {
                     method: 'POST',
                     mode: 'cors',
                     body: blob
                 });
                 let result = response.json();
                 return result;
             };
            makepredict().then( function(result) {
                if (result['translate'] !== "oke"){
                    console.log(result)
                }else{
                    console.log(audioChunks.length)
                }
                

            });
        }
    })
    recorder.start(300)
```

When I not use "audioChunks = audioChunks.slice(-10)" with unlimited data audio then the audio that the server receives via API can be opened in webm format, but when I use code "audioChunks = audioChunks.slice(-10);" limit it to only taking the last 10 data chunks, an error occurs. I cannot open the audio file received by the server in webm format

```
if (audioChunks.length > 10) {
           audioChunks = audioChunks.slice(-10);
       }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAhcA.png)

I have tried many ways but still cannot fix the error. Please support me. Thank you very much

Comment: `an error occurs` more details please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I had add more info problem

Comment: you can click into image to see my error